# Is it possible to set domain on an IP address without dns server?

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, domain

I got an static ip from my isp and port 53 is closed(dns port).
Is there any setting or section in my domain that I can resolve my domain to the static IP without dns server?
thanks in advance

Comment: Assuming you mean that the world should resolve this domain name to your static IP, then no, that's pretty much what DNS servers are for.

Comment: You might want to delete this question, I fear it will get no better answers and it will just float around for ever, otherwise.

Comment: However, to answer the question you didn't ask - you don't need to run your own DNS server in order to have a domain pointed at your server. There are a lot of registrars who will handle DNS for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to run your own DNS server to resolve your domain to a static IP. Most domain registrars provide DNS servers (usually included with domain registration). If this is the case, login to your registrar control panel, find DNS settigns and create "A" record:

```
example.com 86400 A 1.1.1.1
```

Where example.com is your domain name, and 1.1.1.1 is your static IP address.

In the unlikely case that your registrar does not provide DNS servers, you can subsribe to any 3-rd party DNS service for that (There are plenty and some are free).

Comment: So what you're saying is "yes, a DNS server is needed"?

Comment: @MadHatter Hatters make hats, DNS servers resolve domain names. Yes.